# Pandas Drop Duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I am trying to delete duplicates.

my df is as follows after using groupby

```
Unnamed: 0  BCode   Scrip   Group   Type    Open    High    Low Close   Last    PClose  TradesB TTQB    TTVB    ISIN    Date    TDCLOINDI
315370  315370  543348  AXISHETF    B   Q   81.40   81.40   80.59   80.98   80.98   81.63   35  536 43369   INF846K01Z12    2023-05-11  NaN
315371  315371  543348  AXISHETF    B   Q   80.98   81.09   80.10   80.32   80.32   80.98   32  689 55707   INF846K01Z12    2023-05-12  NaN
318763  318763  543348  AXISHETF    B   Q   80.98   81.09   80.10   80.32   80.32   80.98   32  689 55707   INF846K01Z12    2023-05-12  NaN
322649  3391    543348  AXISHETF    B   Q   80.98   81.09   80.10   80.32   80.32   80.98   32  689 55707   INF846K01Z12    2023-05-12  NaN
```

I tried to use drop_duplicates. I did basic data preparation like collecting info and converting all the dtype in to same dtypes per column etc.

I used keep and inplace also.

I need to know the method to groupby ISIN and Date and delete duplicates on basis of Date and  keep first.

Expected Output

315370  315370  543348  AXISHETF    B   Q   81.40   81.40   80.59   80.98   80.98   81.63   35  536 43369   INF846K01Z12    2023-05-11  NaN
315371  315371  543348  AXISHETF    B   Q   80.98   81.09   80.10   80.32   80.32   80.98   32  689 55707   INF846K01Z12    2023-05-12  NaN

Comment: On what basis do you want to drop duplicates?

Comment: Please first search existing questions, if you don't manage to do what you want, **be explicit**, provide clear and minimal examples with the expected output, what you tried and how it failed.

Comment: On basis of Date column duplicate row should be deleted